# Android: when list has ended than it should show button

Tags: android, list

Iamtrying to have a button at the bottom of the list, so when u scroll down and the list has ended than there will be a button "Get more", which will populate the list with more items.

But the button is not visible. this is how my xml file looks like.
Maybee this occurs because of the scroller,, maybe the scroller only works for the list.

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/search_browser"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get more ads" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not really the correct way of doing it.
In your case, the button will ALWAYS be visible at the bottom of the list.
If you want it to be visible only when user scrolls at the bottom, use:

```
yourListView.addFooterView(someFooterView)
```

This footer view can (logically) be any view (button, layout), inflated, or created at runtime.

P.S. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)

P.S.S. In your case, you need to remove your button declaration in XML, leaving only ListView.
And in code do

Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Get more ads");
((ListView) findViewById(R.id.list).addFooterView(button);

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

for your ListView.

I believe however that is more appropriate to have an [auto-growing list](http://www.androidjunkies.com/index.php/2009/10/21/tutorial-autogrowing-listview/).